# gitlab pipeline encountering an "external: failed" error

Tags: git, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, nuxt.js

So I'm trying to create a gitlab page but I'm encountering an "external: failed" error in the pipeline and I'm not sure what's causing it.

When I push my commit to the branch, it tests three stages:

"test: passed", "deploy: passed", "external: failed"

I don't know what the last one is and what causes it.

here's my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: node

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

pages:
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

When I open the error it reads: `now - deployment has failed`

Comment: Does pages work for your other project? Does `npm run build` results with artifacts in `public` folder? Maybe it's stored by default in `dist` and you need to move it to `public`. I tried your CI configuration with replaced `npm` command with simple `mkdir public && echo "Hello" > public/index.html` and it worked fine.

Comment: @makozaki i updated my node version before, and I just tried running a `npm run build`, which gave me an error because `node-sass` was not compatible with the current node version. Updating `node-sass` allowed me to build without problems. Trying gitlab now.

Comment: @makozaki just tried it again, still getting an `external: failed` error. No idea what that is even indicating either.

Comment: @makozaki Ah I worked out what it is, I was experimenting with a platform called Zeit, and that was what was causing the failure.

Answer (score 0):

`external` seems to imply that it's outside of gitlab, in this case it was with Zeit, which I was experimenting with. Disconnecting the relationship fixed this error.